# Multiple api calls (in separate functions) Flask, how do I make them asynchronous so they take less time?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, python-asyncio

I am trying to make a Flask app. It has to make calls to different APIs. Each API call is wrapped in a function which gets and processes the response. How do I make these calls asynchronous so my app takes lesser time to load? Thanks.

A sample function is here, I have a bunch of similar functions which make calls to other APIs-

```
def api_call():
    # Contact API
    try:
        url = f"https://example.com"
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.RequestException:
        return "Oops, there was an error!"
    # Parse response
    try:
        res = response.json()
        return res["key"]
    except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError):
        return "Oops, there was an error!"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have a look to this part of requests documentation, you will find links to other python librairies implementing asynchronous requests call: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#blocking-or-non-blocking

Answer (score 0):

Use threading.

```py
from threading import Thread

def api_caller():
  while True:
    api_call()

Thread(target=api_caller).start()
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have multiple functions like api_call. Is it okay to put them inside the api_caller function? Will each function (api_call ones) get a different thread assigned?

Comment: yes, you can also pass in parameters using `lambda`